# What does ~ ‘^[0-9]+$’ mean in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I’m trying to understand what `~ '^[0-9]+$'` means. Would it be any integer that contains 0-9? Or doesn’t contain 0-9?

Is the `~` equivalent to LIKE in MS SQL?

Comment: POSIX regex matching https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: `^` and `$` indicate matching the start and end of the string, respectively (`^` when used outside `[]`). So the string should consist solely of 1 or more digits, for its entire length.

Comment: That helps alot, thank you!

Comment: `~` is not equivalent to MS SQL's `LIKE`. `~` supports full POSIX compliant regular expressions. Microsoft's LIKE only supports some ranges, but not the capabilities of a complete regular expression (e.g. `^` and `$` are not supported if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @evert you should make that an answer so that this question can be marked as resolved

Answer (score 3):

Looking at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE, you will find, that **~** means:

**"Matches regular expression, case sensitive"**

`'^[0-9]+$'` is a regular expression, with:

- **^**: from string start
- **$**: til string end
- **[0-9]+**: one or more digits.

I don't know how you define integer, but e.g. '0000' is matched as well.

SqlServer does not support complete regular expression syntax out of the box and **like** does not handle regular expressions in PostgreSQL as well, therefore it is not equivalent to **~**.